# Users can't pay each other django-paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, django-paypal

I have an online store where users can pay each other to buy things, I have been testing it with sandbox accounts but I don't think it's working. I really can't get where the issue is

Here is my views.py:

```
def payment_process(request, trade_id):
    trade = get_object_or_404(Trade, id=trade_id)
    host = request.get_host()

    paypal_dict = {
        'business': trade.seller.email, 
        'amount': Decimal(trade.price),
        'item_name': trade.filename,
        'invoice': str(trade.id),
        'currency_code': 'USD',
        'notify_url': 'https://{}{}'.format(host,
                                           reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        'return_url': 'https://{}{}/{}'.format(host,
                                           *reverse('payment_done', kwargs={'trade_id': trade.id})),
        'cancel_return': 'https://{}{}'.format(host,
                                              reverse('home')),
    }

    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    return render(request, 'payment/payment_process.html', {'trade': trade, 'form': form})


@csrf_exempt
def payment_done(request, trade_id):
    # Do some very important stuff after paying ...
    # It would be really nice if someone can help me with a checker
    messages.success(request, 'Your product is in your inbox now')
    return redirect('trade:inbox')
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
    # Prodbox Payment
    path('payment/process/<int:trade_id>/', payment_views.payment_process, name="payment_process"),
    path('payment/done/<int:trade_id>/', payment_views.payment_done, name="payment_done"),
    # Prodbox packages
    path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
]
```

The template which handles paying:

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Payment Process | Prodbox {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container row justify-content-center">
    <div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 col-md-8 bg-white rounded m-4 p-4">
        <section>
            <p>Seller: {{ trade.seller.email }}</p>
            <p>Product: {{ trade.thing }}</p>
            <p style="color: #2ecc71;">Price: ${{ trade.price }}</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h4>Pay with PayPal</h4>
            {{ form.render }}
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

It's **very very important** to redirect users to payment_done view after finish paying, (it would be nice if I had a checker to check if the payment is completed before running done function)

Also, note that I'm emphasizing on users to use their PayPal email account

So why it's not working?!

## Extra information (may not help)

User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def username(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'zeyadshapan2004@gmail.com'

PAYPAL_TEST = False
```

local_settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'sb-dabm93302277@personal.example.com'
PAYPAL_TEST = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it's not working yet provide no information about the problem behavior and why it's not working.

But I suppose that doesn't matter too much, since you're using a bad integration (django-paypal, based on payments standard) for the desired behavior you want of it being "very very important" that the payer return.

---

The integration you should switch to is to integrate v2/checkout/orders, with or without the Checkout-Python-SDK.  You will need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The best front-end UI to use for approval is here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server . Get this working well in a standalone HTML file that calls your 2 django backend routes (via fetch), before you then integrate it as a front-end into your django templates and checkout flow.

For the feature of a user paying another user, use the `payee` object, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/